# UIBarButtonItem on navigation bar with UIBarButtonItemStyleDone style doesn't show in blue color

Tags: iphone, navigationbar, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I have a done button on navigation bar, I want to have it shown as blue. But just doing the following seems doesn't help. What am I missing here? I know that if the navigation bar is in black color, the button will be shown as blue automatically, but I don't want the color of the navigation bar on this view controller to be black.

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)doneButton {
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                                                   target:self 
                                                                   action:@selector(done:)] autorelease];

    return doneButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing combination of NavigationBar and BarItems appearance is not easy tasks before iOS5.

Standard way is to subclass NavigationBar. This nice [sample code](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomBackButton) may help, even if not directly.

In iOS5, you can use "appearance proxy". Nice tutorial is [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define your own done button. As long as it's called 'done' you can use the predefined barbuttonsystemitemdone:

```
   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone Target:...
```